# MYSQL storage increasing unexpectedly (RDS)

Tags: mysql, storage, amazon-rds

I am total newbie to database game.
& I am using mysql 8.0 RDS 20GB free tier.

I don't have much data on it.(**just 300 Mb**)
(wordpress running on ec2 is linked with this rds)

But I always get a mail that **you have exceeded 85% of storage limit.**(approx 17Gb)

Also Under *monitoring* tab in rds panel it shows:- **Free Storage Space (MB) = 19.330Gb** ***(Constantly without any drop)***

**I have turned off :** *general log, slow logs, binlog,*

*i have done these parameter changes*:

```
binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 86400
general_log = 0
innodb_autoextend_increment = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5000000000
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 0
log_output = NONE
max_binlog_cache_size = 5368709120
max_connections = 1000
slow_query_log = 0
innodb_file_per_table = 1
```

SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY count;

```
Highest counts seen on:
buffer_data_written = 6936939008
buffer_pool_size = 402653184
os_log_bytes_written = 313484800
buffer_pool_bytes_data = 204668928
```

Can someone please help me whats consuming these storage. Is this something to do with INNODB?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? Have you tried taking a dump of the DB and having a look see inside? What have you tried to do?

Comment: i have done these parameter changes,(binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 86400 / general_log = 0 / innodb_autoextend_increment = 1 / innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5000000000 / log_bin_trust_function_creators = 0 / log_output = NONE / max_binlog_cache_size = 5368709120 / max_connections = 1000 / slow_query_log = 0 / innodb_file_per_table = 1)

Comment: **SHOW MASTER LOGS** : you are not using binary logging.

Comment: Have you tried taking a dump of the DB - nop.@Uberhumus

Comment: The information in these comments could help people help you.
Please add it to the question.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on AWS RDS MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.  Turning OFF logs only complicates your problems.  General Log should never be on for more than a couple minutes.

Comment: Its an AWS db.t2.micro instance(RAM - 1gb, Core - 1), @Wilson Hauck

Comment: @WilsonHauck PLease check the question, i have added few info,

Comment: @NewGeek Let me know when you have - Posted on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Ouch!  `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5000000000` inside `1GB` of RAM!  This leads to swapping, which uses disk space and slows down MySQL terribly.

Don't set that about, say, 250M.  Even that may be too high.  Do you have other things running in the db.t2.micro?

`max_connections = 1000` -- also too high.  Set it to 20

If you want to change anything else, get some advice first.  The general advice is:  1gb of RAM is very limited; raising tunables can lead to bad results.

Comment: I have edited innodb_buffer_pool_size  = 100mb
max_connection = 20

Thankyou for responding to the question what else should i change, @WilsonHauck I will soon post required info on pastebin

Comment: @NewGeek Analysis will begin after you post data requested on June 1, 2020. Thanks

Comment: @NewGeek - did the links go away?  I'll review the SHOWs, too.